# Django + apache2 -> ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache

python3.4  django1.9 apache2  wsgi

I can import django.core.wsgi like :

[image]

but when run service with apache2 and browse `127.0.1.1` :

[image]

my computer have python2.7 and python3.4.3, so I think when I run service, it's running by python2.7 ,not pyton3.4  -----> `ImportError`

Is this cause??

How can i let service running by python3.4.3????

Comment: the python2.7 is system default

Comment: You need a version of mod_wsgi compiled against Python 3.4.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I had install `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 `

Comment: @weijia.wang thanx man